# How to connect sql developer to a database on localhost? instance=sqlexpress, db name = Equipment

Tags: sql, database, database-connection, sql-server-express, oracle-sqldeveloper

Oracle SQL Developer Version 2.1.1.64

Database created in MS SQL Server management studio 2008.
computer name: server
instance: sqlexpress
DB name: equipment
No security, or windows security I guess.

what do I enter in the following sql developer fields:
hostname, port, SID/service name.

Comment: See [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-may/o38sql-102034.html) paragraph **Connecting to Third-Party Databases**

Comment: I followed the link in your guide exactly.
Set connection name to connection.
Left default password unchecked, checked windows authentication.
typed the computer name (server) into the hostname.
using port 1433.
Still won't connect. I get this error: cannot connect to microsoft sql server on server. :S

Comment: If you connect to remote server you should check use default pasword not windows  auth.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the SQL Server own JDBC Drivers in order to connect to it. SID Is a Oracle only concept.

Take a look here: http://djiang.wordpress.com/2007/02/27/using-oracle-sqldeveloper-to-access-sqlserver/